# How to create own structure in yii2?

Tags: php, zend-framework, yii, yii2

I am php developer. I use to work with `Zend` and `Zend2`. Few days ago i got a new application that was written without engine. It has almost 100 html static pages with SQL code **SESSION**, **POST**, **GET** and other variables.

I want to rewrite it using `Yii2` framework cause i am interested in it. I have not any expirience with it but my friends  told me that it is better to start learning it than Yii1. But i found a little problem for myself. I use to work with file structure like this:

```
/application

-- /base

---- /Controller

---- /Model

-- /news

---- /Controller

---- /Model

/vendor

-- /zend

/www

-- /layouts

---- /base

---- /news
```

but `Yii2` basic and advanced app are totaly different. I would like to make it as my own structure so i went to yii doc and there:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-apps-own.html

"Since it's a bit too much to start building your template from scratch it is better to use one of built-in templates as a base. Let's use basic template. "

> Modify files
>
> Next actually modify the structure of the future application as you
>   like and update readme.

- Well where are the steps how to change structure?
- I understand that yii2 is just beta and documentation is still writing  but why dont they wrote what files should i modify?
- what config params can i use?

As they dont give any answer i decided to ask people here, cause maybe someone also was doing something like that. I would be grateful for information and examples how to change structure in this framework.

p.s yes i can write this project in zend but Yii becomes popular and i would like to have some expirience with it and this project doesnt have any deadlines so it fits perfect for me to start somethng new.

pps. i am bad in english so i would be also greatful for telling me about my mistakes. Thanks.

Comment: You can actually configure Yii2 however you want. There is nothing forcing you to follow the proposed structure form either the basic or advanced templates. That being said I would say it is probably a bad idea to start with a new framework by trying to customise it beyond belief without knowing it :) It is configured the way it is out of the box because this simply works and is a good structure.

Comment: @Blizz i agree with you that there is nothing that can force to use this Yii app structure. And amybe u are right about creating new structure without expirience with this framework. But i dont think that Yii has a good structure) Modules or Bundles( hello Symfony ) are much better(as for me). Quite easy to install or remove or move to another project.

Comment: If you'd like to customize the paths used for each application component, you can by setting them in the application's config. A fair amount of them are configurable, take a look at the [Application's configurable properties](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-application.html), specifically those that have "Path" in the name, to see what's changeable. From there it's a matter of setting up the folder structure, setting the config to match, and ensuring namespaces of the classes are correct.

Comment: Zend structure is more similar to the basic template. But advanced is a much more convenient. Advanced is like a two basic templates (just divided to `admin` panel and `front` with `common` files). And both templates is just examples which helps you fast start,